Modern Search PnP Results web part does not display all items
I use the Modern Search Results PnP Webpart and the PnP Search Verticals. The source is a SharePoint list.
The Search Results web part does not show all items in the list. The list has 3219 items and the web part only shows 3023 items. I think this is because of "vertical query". If I delete vertical query, then all items are shown.
This is my query for the search results web part:
{inputQueryText} path:"https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Interim/Lists/Testlist/" FirmaOWSTEXT:{verticals.value}

What am I doing wrong here?

Most likely some of the items in your path does not match FirmaOWSTEXT:{verticals.value}
In order to locate these try
Path:"https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Interim/Lists/Testlist/*" -FirmaOWSTEXT:{verticals.value
Why these does not match is up to you to find out
